# Como transformar o meu código com struct de memória estática pra dinâmica em C?

Tags: c, struct, memória, alocação

O exercício pede que eu leia informações num arquivo, sendo eles, cpf,nome,email e idade de varias pessoas guarde numa struct, ordene em ordem crescente por idade, se idades iguais por cpf, e print num outro arquivo com o mesmo formato que recebeu,todas as informacoes de uma pessoa é separado por virgula e de uma pessoa pra outra por linha diferente.E eu ja sei qual o tamanho maximo das informações,porém não sei o número de linhas. Eu fiz usando memória estática mas deve criar um vetor de structs usando memória e dinamica e não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
 char CPF[12];
 char nome[41];
 char email[31];
 int idade;
}Dado;

int main()
{
FILE *arq, *arqout;
char ch;
int num=0,i,j,aux;

arq = fopen("read.txt","r");
while( fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch)!= EOF )
    if(ch == '\n')
    num++;
rewind(arq);
Dado pimpolho[num+1];

for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    j=0;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',')
    {
        pimpolho[i].CPF[j] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        j++;
    }
    pimpolho[i].CPF[j] = '\0';
    j=0;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',')
    {
        pimpolho[i].nome[j] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        j++;
    }
    pimpolho[i].nome[j] = '\0';
    j=0;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',')
    {
        pimpolho[i].email[j] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        j++;
    }
    pimpolho[i].email[j] = '\0';
    fscanf(arq, "%d", &pimpolho[i].idade);
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
}

for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (pimpolho[j].idade > pimpolho[j+1].idade)
        {
            pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
            pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j+1];
            pimpolho[j+1] = pimpolho[num];
        }
for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (pimpolho[j].idade == pimpolho[j+1].idade)
        {
            aux = strncmp(pimpolho[j].CPF,pimpolho[j+1].CPF,11);
            if (aux>0)
            {
                pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
                pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j+1];
                pimpolho[j+1] = pimpolho[num];
            }
        }
arqout = fopen("write.txt","w");
for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
     fprintf(arqout,"%s,%s,%s,%d\n",pimpolho[i].CPF,pimpolho[i].nome,pimpolho[i].email,pimpolho[i].idade);
}
fclose(arqout);
fclose(arq);
return 0;
}
```

É possível alterar isso com algumas mudanças?

Comment: Mas a ideia é utilizar uma lista ao invés de um vetor com memoria dinamica ? Caso contrário não tem sentido. Não existe vantagem em criar um vetor de dinamica para o exemplo que tem, e complica o código.

Comment: É eu tbm acho mas o professor ta pedindo pra utilizar memória dinamica e estou tendo dificuldade

Comment: Mas tem de ser com vetor ou é para ser com lista ?

Comment: É pra ser cm vetor eu acho, pelo q eu entendi eu preciso declarar  o struct q eu fiz como uma variável ponteiro e aí alocar o espaço de memória dinamicamente pra quantidade de struct q o programa vai usar, pq é um pra cada linha do arquivo e as linhas dos arquivos variam. Lista ligada ele falou q não usaria ainda

Comment: Deveria fazer tipo no caso do meu programa Dado *pimpolho; e aí trabalhar cm ele assim, mas não estou conseguindo fica dando segmantion fault e outros erros

Comment: Mas se vc conseguir ver uma forma utilizando lista acho q tbm é válido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Alocação dinamica com vetor

A alocação feita de forma dinamica é tão simples como chamar o [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) diretamente:

```
Dado *pimpolho = malloc(sizeof(Dado) * (num+1));
```

O resto que tem funciona pois quando faz `pimpolho[i]` é equivalente a fazer `*(pimpolho + i)`. É simplesmente uma questão de se utiliza sintaxe de array ou sintaxe de ponteiro, sendo que a de array é mais simples e por isso deve utilizar quando possível.

**Nota**: Assim como disse em comentário, para o exemplo que tem isto não trás nenhuma vantagem, muito pelo contrário, torna a alocação mais complicada, assim como pode tornar algumas partes do código mais complicadas (neste caso não) e obriga-lhe a preocupar-se com o liberar da memória com `free` quando já não precisar mais dela. Neste caso como vai utilizar o vetor até ao fim do programa não vale a pena liberar a memória pois já será liberada no termino do mesmo mas noutros casos tem que o fazer sob pena de ficar com vazamentos de memória.

Logo não faça isto nos seus programas a menos que isso tenha um objetivo e vantagens concretas.

### Refatorização

Não quero deixar passar algumas refatorizações importantes que pode fazer e que não são complicadas. Evite ao máximo a repetição de lógica, pois isto trás bem mais problemas do que parece. Olhando para a leitura dos campos que tem:

```
for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    j=0;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',')
    {
        pimpolho[i].CPF[j] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        j++;
    }
    pimpolho[i].CPF[j] = '\0';
    j=0;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',')
    {
        pimpolho[i].nome[j] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        j++;
    }
    pimpolho[i].nome[j] = '\0';
    j=0;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',')
    {
        pimpolho[i].email[j] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        j++;
    }
    pimpolho[i].email[j] = '\0';
    fscanf(arq, "%d", &pimpolho[i].idade);
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
}
```

Isto corresponde na verdade à leitura dos 4 campos, o CPF, nome, email e idade, sendo que as 3 primeiras são iguais. Mas o código foi repetido. Não só fica mais dificil de ler, como fica mais extenso e propicio a ficar errado quando precisar de alterar pois tem que alterar em todos os locais de forma certa. Sempre que isto acontecer abstraia a lógica igual para uma função e chame-a. Ora veja como fica bem melhor:

```
void ler_string_arq(FILE* arq, char *campo_destino){
    int letra = 0;
    char ch;
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    while( ch != ',') {
        campo_destino[letra] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        letra++;
    }
    campo_destino[letra] = '\0';
}

int main() {
   //...
   for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
       ler_string_arq(arq, pimpolho[i].CPF);
       ler_string_arq(arq, pimpolho[i].nome);
       ler_string_arq(arq, pimpolho[i].email);    
       fscanf(arq, "%d", &pimpolho[i].idade);
       fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
   }
```

Na ordenação tem o mesmo problema pois repete duas logicas de ordenação primeiro ordenando por idade, e depois ordenando os que ficaram com idade igual:

```
for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (pimpolho[j].idade > pimpolho[j+1].idade)
        {
            pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
            pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j+1];
            pimpolho[j+1] = pimpolho[num];
        }

for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (pimpolho[j].idade == pimpolho[j+1].idade)
        {
            aux = strncmp(pimpolho[j].CPF,pimpolho[j+1].CPF,11);
            if (aux>0)
            {
                pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
                pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j+1];
                pimpolho[j+1] = pimpolho[num];
            }
        }
```

Isto é inteiramente desnecessário pois você consegue fazer as duas coisas de uma só vez:

```
for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (pimpolho[j].idade > pimpolho[j+1].idade ||
            (pimpolho[j].idade == pimpolho[j+1].idade && strncmp(pimpolho[j].CPF,pimpolho[j+1].CPF,11) > 0)){
            pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
            pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j+1];
            pimpolho[j+1] = pimpolho[num];
        }
```

Não me vou alongar mais nesta parte, mas tenha em mente que a troca feita na ordenação é por copia. Isto pode-se tornar bastante ineficiente se a quantidade de dados for muito grande pois obriga a ter que copiar montes de bytes de um lado para o outro para fazer a troca. A forma de resolver é utilizar um array de ponteiros ao invés de um array com os objetos todos diretamente, mas isso implica alterar o código quase todo, e provavelmente é exagerado para o exercício em causa.

Tem outros pormenores que pode melhorar é claro, mas foquei me apenas nos que são mais fortes e que tem mais impacto no código em geral.

### Alocação dinamica com lista

A pequena diferença de utilizar uma lista ao invés de um vetor já faz todo o sentido, pois na verdade ao utilizar uma lista não precisa de saber quantos elementos tem previamente. Isto faz com que não tenha que percorrer o arquivo duas vezes sendo a primeira para achar o numero de pessoas que existem. Pode ir simplesmente lendo, alocando e ligando os ponteiros entre si. Agora o código em si é mais complicado pois envolve alocações, trocas de ponteiros, liberação de memória, etc...

Primeiro implica alterar a estrutura para que cada pessoa possa ter um ponteiro para a próxima:

```
typedef struct Dado{
//               ^----
    char CPF[12];
    char nome[41];
    char email[31];
    int idade;
    struct Dado* proximo; //<---
} Dado;
```

Depois tem de ter forma de perceber quando chegou ao fim do arquivo. O mais direto é interpretar isso na leitura do primeiro campo o `CPF`. Para isso o mais simples é alterar a função `ler_string_arq` para devolver `0` quando chegou ao fim do arquivo:

```
int ler_string_arq(FILE* arq, char *campo_destino){
//^----tipo int agora
    int letra = 0;
    char ch;
    if (fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch) != 1){ //se não leu um char então chegou ao fim
        return 0;
    }

    while( ch != ',') {
        campo_destino[letra] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        letra++;
    }
    campo_destino[letra] = '\0';
    return 1;
}
```

Depois o `while` de leitura fica agora também bastante diferente:

```
Dado *inicio_lista = NULL, *ultima = NULL; //ponteiros para lista e ultima pessoa

while(1) {
    Dado *pessoa = malloc(sizeof(Dado)); //cria nova pessoa com alocação dinamica
    pessoa->proximo = NULL; //proximo da pessoa criada é nulo
    if (inicio_lista  == NULL){ //se ainda nao tem nenhuma esta é a primeira 
        inicio_lista = pessoa;
    }
    if (ultima != NULL) { //se já tem pessoas liga a anterior a esta
        ultima->proximo = pessoa;
    }

    if (!ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->CPF)){ //se apanhou EOF
        free(pessoa);
        ultima->proximo = NULL;
        break; //sai
    }
    ultima = pessoa;

    ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->nome);
    ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->email);
    fscanf(arq, "%d", &pessoa->idade);
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
}
fclose(arq);
```

Para a escrita seria bastante identico mudando maiortariamente a sintaxe:

```
arqout = fopen("write.txt","w");
Dado* pessoa = inicio_lista;
while (pessoa!= NULL){ //enquanto nao chega ao fim da lista
    fprintf(arqout,"%s,%s,%s,%d\n", pessoa->CPF, pessoa->nome, pessoa->email, pessoa->idade);
    pessoa = pessoa->proximo; //avança para a proxima pessoa
}
```

Note que eu propositadamente omiti a parte de ordenação das pessoas, pois agora com uma lista ligada isso fica bem mais complicado e não me quero alongar mais que a resposta já é bastante grande. Normalmente estas ordenações em listas são feitas com [*Merge Sort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) e acabam por calhar no cenário em que eu indiquei de ser ordenação com ponteiros e por isso são bastante eficientes.

Para além disso a complexidade entre os dois algoritmos de ordenação é bastante diferente pois o *Merge Sort* executa em `O(nlogn)` ao passo que o bubble sort que tem executa em `O(n²)`.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo me ajudou principalmente a parte com lista ligada pois comecei a estudar ela essa semana, eu vou tentar fazer o código utilizando lista ligada agora, se puder dar uma ajuda na parte de ordenação dela eu agradeceria, mas se for muito trabalhoso tudo bem, vou pesquisar mais sobre como ordenar listas

Comment: @HeigonSoldera De nada, fico contente em ter ajudado :). Se depois criar outra pergunta em relação a isso, certamente que poderei ajudar, mas nesta acaba por desviar um pouco do que foi perguntado. Agora antes de o fazer aconselho a explorar bem o código e ter a certeza que compreendeu bem tudo o que foi feito, que saltar de vetor para lista ainda acresce um bom bocado na complexidade devido a ponteiros e gerência de memoria entre outras coisas.

Comment: Ok mt obrigado, eu ainda estou explorando o código e procurando entender tudo, porém ainda estou com dificuldade na ordenação, vou abri outra aba de pergunta então, Muito obrigado por tudo

Answer (score 1):

Espero que lhe ajude:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   char CPF[12];
   char nome[41];
   char email[31];
   int idade;
}Dado;

int main()
{
   FILE *arq, *arqout;
   char ch;
   int num = 0, i, j, aux;
   //melhorando o código
   //arq = fopen("read.txt", "r");
   //verifica se ocorreu algum erro
   if ((arq = fopen("read.txt", "r")) == NULL)
   {
      printf("ocorreu um erro ao abrir o arquivo read.txt!\n");
      return 0;
   }
   //sempre coloque chaves em seu código para que não fique confuso
   while (fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch) != EOF)
   {
      if (ch == '\n')
      {
         num++;
      }
   }
   rewind(arq);
   //primeira modificação transformar a estrutura de Dado estatico para dinamico
   //Dado pimpolho[num + 1];
   Dado * pimpolho = new Dado[num + 1];
   //agora ele e dinamico e sempre verifica se a alocação ocorreu com sucesso
   if (pimpolho == NULL)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      j = 0;
      fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
      while (ch != ',')
      {
         pimpolho[i].CPF[j] = ch;
         fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
         j++;
      }
      pimpolho[i].CPF[j] = '\0';
      j = 0;
      fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
      while (ch != ',')
      {
         pimpolho[i].nome[j] = ch;
         fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
         j++;
      }
      pimpolho[i].nome[j] = '\0';
      j = 0;
      fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
      while (ch != ',')
      {
         pimpolho[i].email[j] = ch;
         fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
         j++;
      }
      pimpolho[i].email[j] = '\0';
      fscanf(arq, "%d", &pimpolho[i].idade);
      fscanf(arq, "%c", &ch);
   }
   //sempre coloque chaves em seu código para que não fique confuso
   for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
      {
         if (pimpolho[j].idade > pimpolho[j + 1].idade)
         {
            pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
            pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j + 1];
            pimpolho[j + 1] = pimpolho[num];
         }
      }
   }
   //sempre coloque chaves em seu código para que não fique confuso
   for (i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
      {
         if (pimpolho[j].idade == pimpolho[j + 1].idade)
         {
            aux = strncmp(pimpolho[j].CPF, pimpolho[j + 1].CPF, 11);
            if (aux > 0)
            {
               pimpolho[num] = pimpolho[j];
               pimpolho[j] = pimpolho[j + 1];
               pimpolho[j + 1] = pimpolho[num];
            }
         }
      }
   }
   //verifica se ocorreu algum erro
   //arqout = fopen("write.txt", "w");
   if ((arqout = fopen("write.txt", "w")) == NULL)
   {
      //libera a memoria utilizada
      delete[]pimpolho;
      printf("ocorreu um erro ao criar o arquivo write.txt!\n");
      return 0;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      fprintf(arqout, "%s,%s,%s,%d\n", pimpolho[i].CPF, pimpolho[i].nome, pimpolho[i].email, pimpolho[i].idade);
   }
   fclose(arqout);
   fclose(arq);
   //terminou libere a memoria utilizada
   delete[] pimpolho;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` e `delete` são palavras reservadas do `C++`!

Comment: me desculpe na verdade foi lapso meu o código e em c e não c++;

Comment: o certo e: Data * <pointer_variable> = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data) * num + 1); e libera free(<pointer_variable>);